# Why does season 2 take place after a five-year time gap?

Tags: production, young-justice

*Young Justice: Invasion* aka Young Justice Season 2's story started 5 year after the conclusion of season 1. Why is this sudden 5 year gap between the story? Did the officials talk about their reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken from the [Station Eight fan site](http://s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/archives.php?lid=664&PHPSESSID=vhvdj31bc1hrdlftth9mfu4t11&qid=16035). It's a quote from Greg Weisman, one of the show's head writers.

> **Greg Weisman says:**
>   "While developing Season One, we had a solid idea of what we had in mind for Season Two - including the time skip. And we had/have solid ideas for Season Three, including another time skip."
>   *[Response recorded on July 17, 2012.]*
>   "We planned on this time jump from day one. **Because we knew, again, that if our show's about growing up, then you can't show a character grow up in 6 months' time**. So the idea is that our first season told 6 months from July 4th to January 1st. Our second season tells another 6 months from January 1st to July 4th, but there's a 5-year gap in-between that we planned."

If you analyze the characters post-jump, you'll see that they have matured and do behave differently, and this isn't something that could be accomplished realistically in even an entire extra season. The show the progress of the Team, and show the results of the track they were headed on, it was necessary to skip forward in time.

Comment: That means another jump will come in third season O.o, anyway nice to see official words.

Comment: @AnkitSharma He recently restated another 5 yearish jump would be happening for Season 3.

Comment: Like I said, cheap trick to mature the characters without the work :)

Comment: @cde Hardly. It's not a cheap trick to do effective, efficient storytelling instead of wasting everyone's time filling in from point A to B. Too many shows do more of the latter, and could take a lesson from YJ.

Comment: You mean get canceled after two seasons with a long break between? I kid. It's still a cheap trick. It's saying "Boom. They are suddenly mature, never mind how".

Comment: We're told how. They fill in the blanks, and season 1 set them on the path. It's the natural conclusion of the events, for them to become more mature. It wasn't made up out of nowhere with them suddenly, unexpectedly different. Even throughout the season we're given details, flashbacks, etc. that fills in the necessary parts of the time jump.